# Don't know what's causing my ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a piece of code which keeps giving me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error and I don't really know why. I think I've set the sizes of the arrays correctly but apparently that isn't true. Even if I set the sizes of the arrays to 100 I still get the error. Below the code you can find the data input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameOfLife {

public static void main(String []args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int length = scanner.nextInt();
    int width = scanner.nextInt();
    int generations = scanner.nextInt();
    Boolean[][] cellsInput = new Boolean[length - 1][width - 1];

    System.out.println();   
    int count = 0;
    int y = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        count++;
        if (count <= length) {
            if (scanner.next().equals(".")){
                cellsInput[y++][count] = false;
            } else if (scanner.next().equals("*")) {
                cellsInput[y++][count] = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            count = 0;
            y++;
            if (scanner.next().equals(".")){
                cellsInput[y++][count] = false;
            } else if (scanner.next().equals("*")) {
                cellsInput[y++][count] = true;
            }   
        }
    }

}
```

}

Input (for example):

```
15 15 3
. . . . . . . . . . . . . * .
. . . . . . . . . . . . * . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . * * *
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
* * * * * * * * . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: don't "think" you've set the sizes correctly: check. Use some tactical `System.out.println()` statements to *verify* that your indices are within valid ranges.

Comment: This `Boolean[][] cellsInput = new Boolean[length - 1][width - 1];` is wrong too.

Comment: Look at the exception stack trace to determine where the exception occurs.  Add println statements ahead of that statement to print out the index values and the array sizes.  Determine what value is going wrong.  Then work backwards through your code to figure out why that value is wrong.  It's the basic debugging process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (count <= length) {
```

Eventually, this is going to try to reference

```
cellsInput[y++][length]
```

Where length is the length of that second array. However, the last index in the second array is actually at `length - 1`.

The problem here occurs because **all arrays in Java start with `0`**. So you always want to do

```
if (count < length) {
```

whenever length is the length is the length of the array.

Length is always the number of objects in the array, which starts counting at `1`.

**Example:**

```
Array arr1 = [a, b, c, d]
Length of arr1 = 4, it has 4 elements

Element   |   Index
--------------------
   a      |    0
   b      |    1
   c      |    2
   d      |    3
```

As you can see index 4 is out of bounds. So when you try to reference `arr1[arr1.length]` you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 4):

For example the following line is wrong:

```
if (count <= length) {
```

Since you use count as index, when count equals length, it exceeds the largest index `length - 1` - thus `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It should be:

```
if (count < length) {
```